# Invalid schema configuration: [OBject Object] is not a valid type within the array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema

i've encountered some error with my schema on mongoose.

my schema looks like:

```
{
accomodations : {
        rooms : {
            type : [{
                rooms : [{
                    type : {
                        id : { type : Number },
                        name : {
                            ita : { type : String },
                            eng : { type : String },
                        },
                        numberOfRooms : { type : Number },
                    },
                }],
                boards : [{
                    id : { type : String },
                    type : {
                        id : { type : Number },
                        name : {
                            ita : { type : String },
                            eng : { type : String },
                        },
                    },
                    amount : {
                        currency : { type : String },
                        directPayment : { type : Boolean },
                        totalPrice : { type : Number },
                        mandatory : { type : Boolean },
                        priceAgency : { type : Number },
                        refundable : { type : Boolean },
                        markupPrice : { type : Number },
                    },
                }],
                amenities : [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed }],
            }],
        },
    }
}
```

if i use "type" as property name i receive an error:
Invalid schema configuration: `[object Object]` is not a valid type within the array `rooms`.See http:// bit.ly /mongoose-schematypes for a list of valid schema types.

it's required for me have a property called type in my schema.

Answer (score 0):

You should never have a field called type. It’s a reserved word in many languages and causes much hassle. Unsure what language you are using I recommend trying to rename to ‘roomType’